# Is there a way to programmatically specify pom.xml path in jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In a declarative pipeline, I manually specify pom.xml path in Jenkinsfile and Jenkins is able to locate it as expected at build time.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {

        stage('Compile') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'MAVEN_HOME') {
                    sh 'mvn -f /Users/jo/.jenkins/workspace/DeclarativePipelineDemo/Demo/pom.xml clean install' //filepath
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now, is there a more elegant way to tell Jenkins to dynamically capture the `workspace/pom.xml` classpath directly from my project so I don't need to manually specify it?

Comment: If  your Jenkinsfile in same repo of pom.xml,  you can use relative path.  When Jenkins run you pipeline, it will automatically clone the repo that holds the Jenkinsfile to Jenkins slave.  If  pom.xml in base dir of project,  you can try  `sh mvn -f pom.xml ...`

Comment: @yong, you are absolutely right. The relative path is working okay. If you put your answer in an answer box, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: The pom file should be in the root of the git repo you are using so by default it shouldn't be necessary to define explicit the pom file via `-f` option.

Comment: @khmarbaise, the pom is not in the root and I don't want to keep it in the root

Comment: @yong, what is the exact meaning of the flag `-f`?

Comment: Why? Not to want it there is not a real reason.

Comment: Because I have a lot of modules in my project and each module has its own pom, so its best to keep each pom as a subfolder in its own module

Comment: You can run `mvn -h` to get the mvn cmd help, it will give accurate description. In short words, if you not use `-f` , maven will try to use `pom.xml` in folder where the mvn cmd executed.  you can think of  `pom.xml` is the default POM file.   If your POM file name is not 'pom.xml'  or your want to use POM file in another folder not the folder the mvn cmd executed, you can use -f , like mvn -f not_default_pom.xml. or  mvn -f  folder1/pom.xml

Comment: Thus -f is an optional argument, depends on the POM file name and location related to  under which folder you run mvn cmd.

Comment: @yong, plus 1 for that answer. Magic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Jenkinsfile in same repo of pom.xml, you can use relative path.

When Jenkins run you pipeline, it will automatically clone the repo that holds the Jenkinsfile to Jenkins slave.

If pom.xml in base dir of project, you can try

```
sh mvn -f pom.xml ...
```